On the Geometric Origins of Cubics
I am just doing a little research on the geometric problems of the ancient geometers that lead to cubic equations.  Two examples I have found are Archimdes On the Sphere and the Cylinder Bk 2, to cut a sphere into two segments with a given ratio; second, is a cubic the came from the construction of a heptagon.
Omar Khayyam had a treatise/essay, now called On the Quadrant of the Circle, in which he reduced a geometrical problem to a cubic.  I can't find an english translation so I don't know what his aim was related to.  If anyone has any info on this that would be helpful.  (I think it is related to heptagons again.)
If anyone else has any more info related to this, please give me more information :)  thank you

Well, there's duplicating the cube, and whether you would include or exclude it from your preferred Answer will clarify what you're looking for.

History of Science and Math SE may be a better place for this question (but it's not off-topic here).

A freely available book for a general history of the subject with a fairly detailed treatment is Taming the Unknown: History of Algebra from Antiquity to the Early Twentieth Century by Victor Katz and Karen Parshall (Princeton University Press, 2014).
On p. 166, Omar Khayyam enters the scene with

[I]slamic mathematicians had continued their assault on the classical
Greek problem of trisecting an angle and had found
constructions—unattempted by the Greeks—of a regular heptagon. Of
their numerous solutions to these problems, many involved the
intersection of two conic sections. It was, however, the mathematician
and poet Umar ibn Ibrahim al-Khayyami (1048–1131) (usually known in
the West as Omar Khayyam), who first systematically classified and
then proceeded to solve all types of cubic equations by this method.

The authors remark that

That al-Khayyami gave this classification [of equations] provides
strong evidence of the major change in mathematical thinking that had
occurred, primarily in Islam, in the more than thirteen hundred years
since Archimedes.Unlike his Greek predecessor, al-Khayyāmı̄ was no
longer concerned with just solving a specific geometric problem, even
though such a problem may have sparked his interest. He wanted to find
general methods for solving all sorts of problems that could be
expressed in the form of equations.

The story of solving cubic equations begins in the ancient world, with Greek geometers laying the foundation, and through the improvement of Hindu mathematics, specifically providing approximate solutions to numerical equations, Arab mathematicians bringing it to its first great culmination. Let us go over the outstanding (known) figures up to Omar Khayyam (it should be remarked that the attributions "Greek" and "Arab" do not necessarily refer to ethnicity, but cultural spheres):
Around 430 BCE, Hippocrates of Chios confronted the Delian problem (the problem of doubling the cube), actually, at the time, more famous than the squaring of the circle among the unsolved problems of antiquity. The task was deceptively simple in its description: Find the side of a cube whose volume is twice that of a given cube. Hippocrates showed that this could be reduced to finding two mean proportionals between a line segment and one twice its length. Mathematically, this condition created a cubic relationship, but the Greeks did not yet possess the algebraic tools to solve such equations. Hippocrates made the crucial first step, but the problem lingered, unsolved.
Not long after, around 429 BCE, Menaechmus took the problem further. He invented the study of conic sections—parabolas, hyperbolas, and ellipses—and demonstrated that by intersecting these curves, the solution to cubic equations could be found. While he did not express his work in algebraic terms, Menaechmus had brought geometry and the nascent idea of cubics together, showing that such problems could be visualised and resolved mechanically.
Diophantus of Alexandria (300 CE) tackled a single cubic equation that arose from a geometric condition involving right triangles. While his focus remained on solving specific numerical problems, Diophantus’ work nudged mathematics closer to algebra, but the broader question of solving cubics still loomed large.
With the rise of the Arab world, the torch passed to new thinkers who took Greek ideas and breathed fresh life into them. Influenced by the Hindu mathematicians, who had advanced algebraic thought significantly, but themselves, did not tackle the cubic problem directly, the Arab mathematicians blended geometry and algebra in ways that would inspire the mathematicians of later centuries.
Al Mahani revisited Archimedes's old challenge of dividing a sphere into segments of a given ratio. He recognised that this ancient geometric problem was fundamentally cubic in nature, marking another step toward understanding these equations. Al Khazin was the first to solve the cubic equations by conic sections. Abu al-Jud solved the equation $x^{3}-x^{2}-2x+1=0$, demonstrating progress not just in theory but in solving tangible equations. Thus was paved the way to Omar Khayyam. Another name to be noted with Khayyam is Sharaf al-Din al-Tusi who improved his methods.
Finally, for those who wish to get familiar this part of the mathematical journey, I'd like to note two quick-read articles that I have recently come across:

M. Vali Siadat and Alana Tholen's Math Horizons article "Omar Khayyam: Geometric Algebra and Cubic Equations" (freely available as an author copy),
David S. Richeson's Quanta article "The Sordid Past of the Cubic Formula."


If you have not yet read it, you might find Jacob Klein's Greek Mathematical Thought and the Origin of Algebra interesting, especially Part Two, Vieta: Reinterpretation of Diophantus.
